# Bluetooth in MFC

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, bluetooth, winsock

I'm trying to write a Bluetooth server as a MFC app and while I got it working as a console app with blocking sockets, I can't get it working using CAsyncSocket.
The error it returns is 10035 - WSAEWOULDBLOCK as soon as I call Accept()

I could copy the code, but it's way too long, so I'll just outline the general idea:
- create, bind regular socket and start listening just like in the Microsoft SDK example app
- attach this socket to CAsyncSocket
- call Accept() (this is where the error occurs)

Any ideas how to get Bluetooth working with CAsyncSocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I've corrected that, but OnAccept, OnConnect(), etc. were never executed, not even when called directly. It turned out that **I had to delete all the temporary files the compiler and linker use** to find out that I was using global shorthand function log() which clashed with log() defined in math.h and which caused some weird behavior.

See this thread for more datails http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=339413

UPDATE: now you can download the finished app and the whole source code on [Brm Bluetooth Remote Control homepage](http://brmbt.sourceforge.net)!

Answer (score 0):

CAsyncSocket's OnAccept member function is called when you can Accept. Subclass CAsyncSocket and handle the OnAccept notification.